# Kendo grid setdatasource renders pager inept

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need grid.setDataSource(ds) to set the filters, but adding this script disables the page count for the grid. So I have the grid set to 20 for page size, but instead, it shows it all within the view. The pager acts like it works, meaning, if you click left or right, the pages change and the count changes in the pager, but the actual view doesn't change since it loads all of the data and ignores the page size. So I'm stuck on how to make it all work together.

```
  var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
  var ds = populateAwardDataSource(JSON.parse(results));
  ds.read();
  grid.dataSource.data(ds.data());
  grid.setDataSource(ds);

  function populateAwardDataSource(dataJson) {
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "json",
        data: dataJson,
        batch: true,
        serverPaging: true,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "clientProgramId",
                fields: {
                    index: { type: "number" },
                    cycle: { type: "number" },
                    ID: { type: "string" },
                    action: { type: "command" }
                }
            },
        },
        pageSize: 20,
    });
    return dataSource;
}
```

If I take out the script grid.setDataSource(ds);, the pager works like it should, but then the filters don't get set with the correct data.

Comment: could you post relevant html?

Comment: well the only html is the actual grid itself which is <div id="grid"></div>, thats it

Answer (score 0):

OK I was able to figure it out. Instead of resetting the data from the results, resetting the grid datasource seems to work. So:

```
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var ds = populateAwardDataSource(JSON.parse(results));
        ds.read();
        grid.dataSource.data(ds.data());
        grid.setDataSource(grid.dataSource);
        grid.refresh();
```